# jScript - How to "mirror" a matrix (multidimensional array)

Tags: javascript, arrays, matrix, multidimensional-array

My latest exercise asks me to do this:

"Given a multidimensional array which is N*M (where N are rows, M are columns), create a function that returns TRUE if the multidimensional array can be considered as a Mirror. This Multidimensional array can be considered a MIRROR if array[i][j]===array[j][i]".

My idea was pretty basic (consider the array as already initialized) :

Small edit as requested---

```
var rows=prompt(), columns=prompt();   //I usually use an asknum() function
   var matrix = new Array (rows);
   function myMatrix (arr,col,rows){
    for(i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
    myArray[i] = new Array() 
    for(j=0;j<col;j++){
      myArray[i][j]=asknum();  //this is a prompt function specified to insert numbers
    }
  }



myMatrix(matrix,columns,rows);



var isMirror=0;  //counter to check if it is or is not a mirror
var getMatrix = function (rows,columns) {
                    if(rows===columns) {  
                       return rows*(columns-1);
                     }
                    }
function findMirror (arr)  {    
for(i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
 for(j=0;j<arr[i].length;j++){
  if(arr[i][j]===arr[i.length-1-j][j.length-1-j] && i!=j){
     isMirror++;
    }
   }
  }
if(isMirror===getMatrix(rows,columns)){
  return true;
} else {
  return false;
 }
}

findMirror(matrix);
```

2 Possible matrix(es) so that you can better understand my way of thinking it:

```
  3x3              5x5
[1,2,3]        [1,2,3,4,5]
[2,1,2]        [2,2,2,1,4]
[3,2,1]        [3,2,3,2,3]
               [4,1,2,4,2]
               [5,4,3,2,1]
```

As you can see by yourself, in a 3x3 mirrored (not counting the elements of the main diagonal) the number of mirrored elements is 6, and 3*2=6. In the 5x5 mirrored, the number of elements is 20, and 5*4=20 and so on. I've tried it 'til a 7x7 but I guess its a working theory so I studied my functions around this possibility.

Help, thank you <3

Comment: Could you post an example of input/output? How do you represent your matrix in JS when you pass it to the function?

Comment: You describe a problem to solve.  You have code.  What exactly is it that isn't working in your code that you need help with?

Comment: i have a non-working code, otherwise i woudlnt have posted it XD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My first observation is that you only need to iterate through the top half of the matrix - for example having checked if array[1][2] == array[2][1], there is no need to go on and check that array[2][1] == array[1][2]. And as you already noticed there is no need to check if array[x][x] == array[x][x].

Secondly, as soon as you find one element that does not match, you can immediately return false. So, counting the number that did match and then checking the count at the end is unnecessary.

Finally, if the dimensions of the matrix are not the same then of course it cannot be a mirror.

This might work:

```
function checkMirror(arr) {
    for (i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
        if (arr.length != arr[i].length) {
            return false;
        }
        for (j=i+1; j<arr.length; j++) {
            if (arr[i][j] !== arr[j][i]) {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```